# Flexible columns

Tags: html, css

I want make flexible columns. When a right is longer than the left, the left increases the length of the right and vice versa. In addition, I want to see green has always been at the bottom of the left column. Now, I make min-height but its not solution ;)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SrFXB.jpg

```
<section class="left">
  <section class="green"></section>
</section>
<section class="right"></section>
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS and/or a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the layout with `display:table-cell` and some clever alignment tricks. This should get you going.

http://jsfiddle.net/BEkDT/